# Any alternativer to EXPLAIN command in BigQuery to validate table existence?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, explain

I am trying to use the EXPLAIN command in BigQuery to validate if a table exists in my database. Ex:

> EXPLAIN SELECT 1 FROM table

However, when I run the command, I get an error saying that EXPLAIN is not a recognized keyword. Is there a way to use EXPLAIN in BigQuery to check if a table exists, or is there an alternative method I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Querying the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES view is probably a better solution

Answer (score 0):

You can also try Bigquery [Exists](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/subqueries#exists_subquery_concepts) command, an example given below:-

```
select if(exists(select * from proj.dataset.table), 'yes exist', 'not exist') as result;
```